# Microsoft Graph + Outlook - Don't returned list tasks

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

GET-request to "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tasks" return this json-string:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#tasks","value":[]}
```

But I have some tasks in my MS-account.

And GET-request to "/beta/ME/tasks" don't worked and return StatusCode - Not Found.

Why? How send the right request and get my tasks in json-string?

**Updated:**

At first I did not apply the scope `Tasks.ReadWrite`, but after that everything remains the same as it was.

Do I understand correctly: Microsoft Graph tasks is not Outlook Tasks, Microsoft Graph tasks is Planner's tasks?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Microsoft Graph tasks are Planner tasks. Outlook tasks are currently not accessible via Microsoft Graph, though we're considering adding them as well.

Comment: Please voice requests for this feature here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/5904632-task-management-api